# Difficult Query For Transact SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering how you would do this in Transact SQL:

Suppose you have a string of values in a database that are comma delimited, such as:

```
"1,2,3,4,5"
```

In Transact SQL, what is the syntax you would use to:

1. Read the string
2. Insert each integer on a separate line in the database.

For example, after this Transact SQL statement has been run, the database will have five additional rows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is this easy?

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  Google `string_split()`.

Comment: If you're using a older version of SQL Server prior to 2016 there is no built-in `string_split()` function. In that case, you'll need to implement your own using existing ones, as user defined function or SQLCLR function. This is one of the best I've found that's not SQLCLR based. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Answer (score 0):

You can use STRING_SPLIT function for this purpose

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400) = '1,2,3,4,5,7', @idx int  

while LEN(@tags) > 1  
begin  
    select @idx=CHARINDEX(',',@tags);  
    select SUBSTRING(@tags,1,@idx-1);  
    set @tags = SUBSTRING(@tags,@idx+1,LEN(@tags)+1)  
end  
select SUBSTRING(@tags,1,@idx-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input...  How would you use this to INSERT these values into a database?  Say the database name is "Database1" and the tablename is "Table1"?

Comment: Ok, suppose your Table1 have a column named field1, varchar(max). The INSERT should go like this,
insert into table1 (field1) select SUBSTRING(@tags,1,@idx-1);